# Adding camera drag in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, drag

I am writing a 3D chess game since its helping me learn Unity. I am trying to implement camera dragging when the middle mouse button is pressed down. The following code does this, but the problem is that its slow:

```
bool wasDraggingCamera = false;
Vector3 lastScreenMousePosition;
Ray lastMousePosition;

void Update ()
{
    UpdateDrag();
}

void UpdateDrag()
{
    var willDragCamera = wasDraggingCamera;
    wasDraggingCamera = Input.GetMouseButton(2);
    var mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (willDragCamera && Input.mousePosition != lastScreenMousePosition)
        transform.position = transform.position - (mousePosition.origin - lastMousePosition.origin);
    lastScreenMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    lastMousePosition = mousePosition;
}
```

You see, the main issue is that the delta between two points on the camera in world-space is quite small depending on how far you are from the subject chess board, but amplifying it by multiplying the product of `(mousePosition.origin - lastMousePosition.origin)` is actually going to cause an exponential speed increase, for example. I am not quite sure but can someone help me figure out how I can actually increase the speed at which the drag happens with the above code? I'm a bit stumped here.

Comment: how about multiplying the delta by some linear factor of your distance from the board? so the further you are from it, the larger the delta multiplier. or better yet just move the camera position based on [screen coordinates](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html), and not with world coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some much simpler logic:

```
Vector3 lastDragPosition;

void Update()
{
    UpdateDrag();
}

void UpdateDrag()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        lastDragPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
    {
        var delta = lastDragPosition - Input.mousePosition;
        transform.Translate(delta * Time.deltaTime * 0.25f);
        lastDragPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```